# What's a good wizard for creating HTML RSS feed widgets?

Tags: free, rss, feeds, widgets

I'm looking to take a RSS feed XML link, and incorporate its contents into my site using a free online wizard to handle the scripting. To be more specific, I'd like to know if there's a tool that experienced webmasters use that's a) free [or low cost], b) creates standards-based HTML4+ code, and c) generates a list with summary with a slow scrolling effect as one of its options.

Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any wizards, but searching for "vertical RSS news scroller" reveals several tutorials to create JavaScript-based news tickers, such as [this one.](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/10/automatic-news-ticker-with-vertical.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [feed2js](http://feed2js.org/). It does the first two things you want. You can either use it from their site, or download the code for more customisation. You could use jQuery to achieve the smooth scrolling.

Comment: This looks like what I was asking for - thanks. I'm still learning jQuery, so could you suggest a method for implementing a smooth scrolling effect? Much appreciated.